# Passing event as props

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I have a custom button component that I can reuse across the other page as a different button and still learning to use typescript. But when I tried to connect to Metamask, it doesnt prompt anything and I'm not sure on which part that need to be fixed

From my CustomButton.tsx

```
interface CustomButtonProps {
  btnType: string;
  title: string;
  styles: string;
  handleClick?: () => void;
}

const CustomButton = ({
  btnType,
  title,
  styles,
  handleClick,
}: CustomButtonProps) => {
  return (
    <button
      type={btnType}
      className={`font-epilogue font-semibold text-[16px] leading-[26px] text-white min-h-[52px] px-4 rounded-[10px] ${styles}`}
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
      {title}
    </button>
  );
};
```

So I use this component in my Navbar as follows:

```
// usecontext to connect to the Metamask
import { useAccount } from "../context";
// custombuton component
import { CustomButton } from "./";

const Navbar = () => {
  
  const { connect, account } = useAccount();
 <div className="sm:flex hidden flex-row justify-end gap-4">
        <CustomButton
          btnType="button"
          title={account ? "Create a campaign" : "Connect"}
          styles={account ? "bg-[#1dc071]" : "bg-[#8c6dfd]"}
          handleClick={() => {
            if (account) <Link href="create-campaign" />;
            else return connect;
          }}
        />
</div>
```

Comment: You are missing a `return` from the `NavBar` component

Comment: tried with else return connect still doesnt work

Comment: @0xhax please update your question with the latest changes

Comment: what are you trying to do in `handleClick`?
its return type is void and you can't return anything from it.
then again why are you creating a `Link` inside it?
and I'm guessing  `connect` is a function correct?

Comment: If it's detect the account function from my usecontext it will redirect to that page and yes connect is a function. So what should I put for handleClick?